# Calculate the rate of cooling of huge amount of water to room temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, cooling

Is it possible to calculate the rate of cooling of huge amount of water to room temperature given the following parameters:

The surface of water in contact with air
the surface of water in contact with the plastic of water
the amount of water in liters
the room temperature (it's around 15°C)
water initial temperature

This is to solve a problem in my fish tank during winter, I've searched a lot online, found some calculators but nothing suitable to me, i'm not too much of a mathematician, i'd appreciate a hand, with a process or formula that can help, if any other data is needed i can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Convective heat loss to air from the water surface $(A_w)$:

$$q_{w,a} = h_{w,a}A_w(T_{water} - T_{air})$$

Convective heat loss to the air from the plastic surface $(A_p)$

$$q_{p,a} = h_{p,a}A_p(T_{plastic} - T_{air})$$

Conductive heat loss through the plastic thickness $(t_p)$

$$q_{p} = k_{p}A_p\frac{T_{water} - T_{air}}{t_p}$$

Suppose you know the initial temperature of the water $T_{0w}$ and air temperature $T_{air}$ (that suddenly fell to its value).

You proceed by interactions, calculating the sum of heat loss each time for all boundaries. Then calculating the new water temperature by:

$$q = mc(T_{1w} - T_{0w})$$

Hard to find are the empirical coefficients of convection and conduction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

Imagine that you had a model, as sketched out by Claudio Saspinski above, and you use it to solve for the characteristic cooldown time of your fish tank. It would be unwise to assume the model was perfectly accurate (due to the uncertainty of the heat transfer coefficients, etc.), so you test the model by putting a thermometer into the tank, shutting off the heat to it (but leaving the circulating pump on), and recording the temperature of the tank once an hour. You then compare the calculations with the actual behavior of the tank, to verify the correctness of your model.

Now you can see that a second approach is to simply instrument the tank and collect actual data off it. This is a safe way to get the answers you need because it accounts for the actual values of the coefficients.